# Watson IBM credential, script python

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I need to consume this credential?
url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api",
  "username": "xxxxxx",
  "password": "yyyyyy"
What libraries or somebody has developed a script to consume watson service?

Answer (score 0):

A number of SDKs are built for easily working with Watson developer cloud.

Here is the python one. It has examples which show you how to use it.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Like @Simon says, for call the API Conversation from IBM Bluemix, you will use the SDK watson-developer-cloud, check the Python SDK [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk).

But, I saw you need to call the *conversation* API, I really recommend you check the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?python#). This page has a lot of references for use Conversation with Java, Node, Curl and Python. IF you don't find some what you like to do with Python, try to see other language example and do the same logic for your purpose.

For your purpose, and call the conversation API with Python, you will need to do something like:

Install the SDK library:

```
pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud
```

And the code for call the API:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import ConversationV1

conversation = ConversationV1(
  username='{username}',
  password='{password}',
  version='2017-05-26'
)
```

See one [project](https://medium.com/ibm-developer-advocacy/how-to-build-a-recipe-slack-bot-using-watson-conversation-and-spoonacular-api-487eacaf01d4) from IBM Developers with Conversation (Python).

Comment: Thanks , I found the same day.